# Add the types inferred by the TypeScript compiler to the original TS source code

Tags: typescript, type-inference, tooling

With TypeScript you can either specify types explicitly or let the compiler infer them.

Is there a way to add the types that are inferred to the original source code?

Eg I would start with:

```
private posX = 0;
private posY = 0;
private sizeX = 0;
private sizeY = 0;
```

I would run type inference, and since the types can be inferred in that case I would get:

```
private posX: number = 0;
private posY: number = 0;
private sizeX: number = 0;
private sizeY: number = 0;
```

This way when editing the code I could check if the inference worked as I expect, and I could manually provide more restrictive types if appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a library exists or not, but you can probably do that using the [compiler api](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes this is definitely possible. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already a tool to do it ;-)

Comment: And I don't blame you. But, this isn't the place to ask such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone actually implemented this!

> **https://github.com/urish/typewiz**